# Issue in running a client js file in Node js express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am facing a issue in node js express[as I am new to node js].. My use case is I have an three directories[root directory, routes,html files] . In root directory, I am having index.js file which has port information, In routes directory, having an route file for mentioning all routes of api. In html files, I am having static html files + client.js file.. When I go to **/api/getlist** route, I am sending an html file.. In that html file, when clicking on a button, I am trying to run a client.js file to do some validations..but console shows

> getlist:30 GET http://localhost:5000/api/client.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Index.js

> 

````
const express = require('express')
> const dotenv = require("dotenv").config(); 
>const port =require('debug')('log:port') 
>const get =require('debug')('log:getroute') 
>const routes = require('./routes/routes') 
>const app = express() 
>const bodyParser =require('body-parser')
> 
> 
> // app.use(express.static('/Users/gowthamkishore/Desktop/folder/node
> js/project'))
> 
> 
> app.use('/api',routes) app.use(express.static('htmlfiles'))
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
> app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
> 
> 
> app.listen(process.env.PORT,(req,res)=>{   
> port(process.env.PORT,'Port information') })

 routes.js

>  const express = require('express') 
>const router = express.Router() 
>const path = require('path') 
>const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
> const fs = require('fs')
> 
> router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
> router.use(bodyParser.json());  router.use('/client',
> express.static(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname,'../'),'/htmlfiles/client.js')));
> 
> router.get('/getList/:id',(req,res)=>{
>     console.log(req.params)
>     res.sendStatus(200) })
> 
> 
> 
> router.get('/getlist',(req,res)=>{
>     console.log(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname,'../'),'/htmlfiles/client.js'))
>     console.log(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname,'../'),'/htmlfiles/firstpage'),'Logger')
>     res.sendFile(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname,'../'),'/htmlfiles/firstpage.html'))
>     console.log('In get List')
> 
> })
> 
> router.post('/newlist',async (req,res)=>{
>     res.send('ys') console.log(req.body) res.send(req.body.fname) })
> 
> 
> module.exports = router


firstpage.html

 ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   
  </head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>


<form action="http://localhost:5000/api/newlist" method="POST">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Gowtham"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Kishire"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <h1>Node + Express + MongoDb example</h1>
  <p id="counter">Loading button click data.</p>
  <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>


<button id = 'information'>Click here</button>


</body>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</html>
```

Client.js
```
console.log('Client-side code running');

const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
});```

Please help me on this case
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date-fns` package for it. It is `tree-shakeable`, so only what you import will go in final bundle. There is the function called `differenceInHours()` which you can use.

package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns

differenceInHours: https://date-fns.org/v2.19.0/docs/differenceInHours

One parameter would be the Date from the database, and second parameter would be the current Date. For current Date you can just send `Date.now()`.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.